# Refinery CMS - it creates an empty Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-management-system, refinerycms, ruby-2.0

I'm trying to create an application using Refinery CMS. What I did was exactly from the tutorials:

```
refinerycms rickrockstar
cd rickrockstar
rails s
```

It creates an empty Rails app which I can create by saying `rails new my_new_app`

What did I do wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I also says "`run bundler`" and then "`Bundler::GemfileNotFound`" if I run as "rails new -m http://refinerycms.com/t/2.0.0"

Comment: When you say empty, did you check by starting the server and navigating to http://localhost:3000, or by looking at the code? Is there a Sqlite database file?

Comment: @iain I navigated to localhost3000 and it got the public static rails page. there is o sqllite db file